# Something wrong in the datetime format

Tags: c#

When i compile the application in my laptop it runs fine but when i run the same application in the server something is wrong with the date format. But when i checked the system date time format wit my laptop and server it the same format. Can anyone tell me what is wrong.

Comment: More info. What do you mean by something is wrong with the format?

Answer (score 1):

You also have to check the default culture set in the laptop and the server. Are they running in the same culture? Different culture settings will have different default time formats.

Answer (score 1):

Is your application running on the server under a different user account?  Regional settings are per-user so date and time formats will depend on the user that the application is running under.  You can log in as the application user and check the Regional settings to determine if that's the issue.

This is really common in ASP.NET where the developer builds the app on their workstation and upon deployment to QA or production they find that Regional settings differ because the App Pool is using a service identity.

Answer (score 0):

Is the system clock running UTC, and the OS changing it to local time on the server.  This is a pretty common configuration, but will break programs that bypass the OS's functions to retrieve the date/time.